# pandas merge matching different rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames with some item (a,b,c..) names in old version and new version in different orders. Here old_a and new_a are different words (example `old_a='cat', new_a='dog'`). Very simplified;

[image]

I would like to get the data frame below;

[image]

I can find the corresponding indexes by

```
df= pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on=['names'])
```

But this gives me the below df, how do i get from here to desired above data frame?

[image]

Comment: What is the output that you are getting when you use `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['names'])`

Comment: Sorry, no I used the wrong data set, this just gives me the column name, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
In [829]: df1
Out[829]: 
   names
0  old_a
1  old_b
2  old_c
3  old_d

In [828]: df2
Out[828]: 
   names
0  new_a
1  new_b
2  new_c
3  new_d

In [830]: df = pd.concat([df1.rename(columns={'names':'old_names'}),df2.rename(columns={'names':'new_names'})], axis=1)

In [833]: df
Out[833]: 
  old_names new_names
0     old_a     new_a
1     old_b     new_b
2     old_c     new_c
3     old_d     new_d
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but df1 and df2 don`t have the same orders in my case